# How to choose a type of a lens for a particular optical component?

Tags: optics, lenses

With almost no experience in optics, I am trying to create a system that looks something like that:

[image]

The idea is to be able to focus the parallel wide beam (shown in broken line between lens 214 and lens 216) by the lens 216 on the pupil in such way, so the beam spreads on the back of the retina providing 50 degree FOV.

The lens 216 looks like a spherical be-convex lens. Is this the type of the lens I should use, of how do I choose the type of the lens for a lens 216? I can not find a large aperture lens with small focal point on Thorlabs or Edmund Optics, that is aspherical. However, found [this](http://www.ocularinc.com/ocular-maxac-20-diopter.html) lens on one of the websites, but I do not know if it would be a good fit for in my case.

It would be nice if someone could explain what type of lens, or a set of lenses, should be used in place of the 216 lens.

Comment: What you are looking for can probably not be done satisfactorily with a single optical element (not even with an aspherical one). Based on your problem (converting an almost parallel beam into a wide field of view), I would suggest to look at commercially available astronomical eyepieces. The design of these is non-trivial and has basically been done for you by specialists who know everything there is to know about the optics of the human eye. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyepiece. High quality eyepieces are available from a large number of telescope manufacturers.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you think about the lens I referenced in the qestion [OL-20A](http://www.ocularinc.com/ocular-maxac-20-diopter.html). It is not good enough?

Comment: @CuriousOne Also, I did not mention that this system is for retinal imaging. Thus that lens is intended to spread the light across the retina (for illumination).

Comment: As a general point of advice: technical optics is an engineering discipline. It uses mathematics to optimize solutions, not guesswork, as you seem to assume. Unless someone does the required calculations, your chances of getting this right by guessing are close to zero (I've been there). May I suggest that you hire a professional to do this design job? There are plenty of people in industry who are experienced with these systems and who can help you. More likely than not, a suitable solution already exists, and you can buy what you need, already. No need to reinvent the wheel.